# Is it possible to add a letter or some other character in front of an incrementing field?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

What I would like to do is have my primary key field (or another field as long as it accepts auto incrementing) auto increment with a letter in front of it. For example:

I would like to be able to make pk equal A1,A2,A3 in one table, and if i choose, B1, B2,B3 in another table. Is this possible with django? mysql? The field doesn't have to be the primary key field as long as it auto increments. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in MySQL that will do this automatically for you.  You do have a couple of options though.

***Option 1 (Better Option):***

Use two separate fields and then when pulling information combine them:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  id_adder char(1) not null
)
```

Then when use the following with all other fields to get the results you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(id_adder, CAST(id AS CHAR)) AS FullPK FROM MyTable
```

***Option 2:***

You can get what the next value should be based on the last value that was entered:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  id varchar(15),
  OtherField varchar(30),
  UNIQUE (id)
)
```

The insert may look something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, OtherField)
SELECT CONCAT('A', CAST(CAST(RIGHT(id, LENGTH(id) - 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1 AS CHAR)),
       'Other Field Value'
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with an auto-incrementing field, exclusively.  You could set up another column inside each table with a single letter identifying the table, have an auto-incrementing column, and then make the key the combination of the two.  You can also set this up using a trigger.

However, this doesn't fully make sense because the letter really isn't needed within a single table.

I suspect that you are trying to solve a different problem, which is to have multiple "types" of an entity in different tables (say a table of contacts, with one for email, one for mail, one for telephone contact).  If so, another approach is to have a master table of everything with an auto-incrementing id, and then to use this id in the subtables, defined with a 1-1 relationship.